# Google Places AutoComplete doesn't allow selecting on ionic application

Tags: android, jquery, angularjs

I have an ionic application, and I am using this plugin to get the names of places

> https://github.com/kuhnza/angular-google-places-autocomplete

my code is as follows:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="user.locationText" placeholder="Location, Area or City" id="locationModalBox" ng-change="updateCity(user.locationText)" g-places-autocomplete required/>
```

The issue is, that I can't seem to select a place form the drop down that shows. I have tried using the snippet below, but it doesn't work on the android phone.

```
$(document).on({
    'DOMNodeInserted': function() {
        $('.pac-item, .pac-item span', this).addClass('needsclick');
    }
}, '.pac-container');
```

Comment: hi noor , if you have json of city, place ad all other information. then plzz you try .. https://github.com/tnr2394/autoCompleteTextbox

Comment: @YashShukla, no this not pre-populated from a json. It uses the Google places API.